# Is there a command to reply to the last private message in irssi?

Tags: irssi

That is, can I type something like `/reply <reply_msg>` after someone private messages me?

Comment: Does just hitting tab (it cycles so you can hit it more than once) do what you want?

Comment: Irssi is an IRC client there is nothing for this in IRC. You could probably do something with a macro.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking for `/query <nick>`

http://carina.org.uk/screenirssi.shtml#8

> To Message someone in private use the command "/msg  ". For example "/msg Trapper hello!" will private message me with the word "hello". "/query " will open a pm (private message) with a person but not send a message - you can type that in seperately. This is useful if you have something to say and you want to avoid the chance that something will accidentally end up in a public channel.

I tried in irssi version 0.8.15-4ubuntu3, and found that any time I set up a query window, all PMs to and from go to that window. And all messages sent from that window are also a PM.

It's very cool.